# Breakpoint in mojarra source to get a list of @ManagedBean name to class mappings

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean, mojarra

I'd like to get a point of @ManagedBean name to class mappings in the Mojarra 2.0 source.

Can someone tell me where I can set a breakpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you would like to debug, but the mapping is hold in the `managedBeans` property of the `com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ManagedBeanConfigHandler` class.